# Robot Framework Test Template Setup argument problems

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, browser-automation

I've got several working Robot Framework tests that I'm trying to consolidate into one test suite and run through a template. The tests are functionally the same, just being executed from a different URL. So that's the one parameter that's different. I'm trying to pass the URL into each test case, but I am getting an error: "Keyword 'Setup' expected 0 arguments, got 2."

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Login tests
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Suite Setup         Setup
Test Template       Template 1

*** Variables ***
${browser}          chrome
${url1}             https://<test.url1>
${url2}             https://<test.url2>
${url3}             https://<test.url3>

*** Keywords ***
Setup
     Open Browser               ${url}  browser=${browser}  options=add_argument("<argument>")
     Maximize Browser Window 
     Set Selenium Speed         0.2s
     Log To Console             Setup complete. Logging in...

Template 1
    [Arguments]                 ${url}  ${browser}=${browser}
    Setup                       ${url}  ${browser}
    <Login tests>

*** Test Cases ***
Site 1 Login
    ${url1}

Site 2 Login
    ${url2}

Site 3 Login
    ${url3}
```

Anybody have any ideas? Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Setup` with two arguments, like the error says:

```
Template 1
    [Arguments]                 ${url}  ${browser}=${browser}
    Setup                       ${url}  ${browser}
    <Login tests>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! So, that's fixed and it does indeed run now, but after running through the first test case of ${url1}, it opens another browser and goes back through the same URL. It doesn't follow on to ${url2}.

Comment: Please accept my answer as the correct one. The other problem is because Setup needs to have the URL as argument.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! It all works just fine now. Awesome, thanks again for your help!

Comment: I would like to see my answer as Accepted and Green ;).